# ¿Como puedo evitar que se detenga la compilacion en Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

cada que quiero elegir una foto para guardarlo en mi bd. Se abre el explorador de archivos, selecciono la imagen. Y se detiene la depuracion de visual studio. No bota ningun error, solo se cierra.

[image: Modal Producto]

Dejo el fragmento del codigo de la etiqueta

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <img id="img_producto" height="197" width="220" class="border rounded mx-auto d-block img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="fileProducto" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg" onchange="mostrarImagen(this)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Dejo el codigo de la funcion

```
function mostrarImagen(input) {
        if (input.files) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("#img_producto").attr("src", e.target.result).width(220).height(197)
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: En el menú "View" de visual studio, hay una opción que dice "output" (no recuerdo cómo es en español), en esa ventana hay un menú desplegable y una de las opciones es "debug". Ahí encontrarás la excepción que está deteniendo el proceso